# Use different IP's for each vm on virtualbox (Dedicated Server)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, proxy, ip, dedicated-server

### I have a dedicated server with a /29 block, how can I setup 8 linux vm and assign each vm with a different IP? Is it possible?

edit 1 - Hello, guys. Thank you so much for your answers. I am using windows server  2008 as host, and I am trying to (still learning basics) use linux ubuntu as vm. I just installed ubuntu 16.04 and turned machine off to try to configure the VM network settings, but haven't seen anything that made me advance on this quest to give this VM one of the /29 IPs. So for your informations I learned that /29 are 5 IPs instead of 8, but thats still cool. And also I have a couple private HTTPS proxies that I could use (on host) with proxycap or proxifier, but I wouldn't know how to link the proxy to each vm. I am sorry If my text is confused and I hope you guys can understand.

edit 2 - I manage to manually add the extra ips, the one I access via windows remote desktop is xxx.xxx.149.162 and I add .163 to .166 but just to test, added .168 and 169 and it accepted on the ipv4 setings, even I am sure I don't own the ips, and the .167 could not be added for some reason, tried several times.

[image: no description]

edit 3 - So maybe I am starting to understand, my block doesn't start on .162 , but on .161, and the 5 usable are .162 to .166. Alright! That explains a lot.

edit 4 - @HazardousGlitch Hello, I could access the server using from .162 to .166, about the subnet mask, I googled and it says to use like this, then used on all ips but .162 which you can see its different. Should I put different values on all ips or can you point me the errors? Also, I am still unable to link the ips to the vm, how should I proceed?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Adding IPs to VMs is easy and well within the normal capabilities of any hypervisor. So what have you tried so far? Please use the edit button to add context and what you have tried.

Comment: @music2myear it may be possible, but it aint very practical. Broadcast and network tskes you down to 6, then you have the host itself, so 5. If the /28 is routed over a /30 (or similar) you would be better off with internal IPs on the VNs and port mapping.

Comment: Oh, yea. Networking has never clicked with me the way other tech subjects have. The available IPs in a /29 just isn't the first thing my mind calculates.

Comment: Just to be clear, /29 has 6 useable IPs. One will be used for the default route, which is likely the router to the interwebs, and remaining 5 are for whatever.

Comment: You're able to add whatever (valid IPs) you want but you'll never get the traffic for IPs that aren't being routed to your server by your provider. Also, you entered the wrong subnet mask for .163 and I suspect for .168 as well because you would have likely gotten an error.